# Angular Validator.maxlength show message on keypress

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to show validation messages on keypress for certain validations such as max length. Currently, they show if you tab out or click out of the field.

Form group:

```
this.shortForm = this.fb.group({
  fName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]]
})
```

template:

```
<md-input-container>
 <md-error *ngIf="shortForm.get('fName').hasError('maxlength') && shortForm.get('fName').touched">
      Maximum of 50 characters
 </md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

Also does not work:

```
<md-input-container>
 <md-error *ngIf="shortForm.get('fName').hasError('maxlength')">
      Maximum of 50 characters
 </md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

How can I display the error message if the user input hits max-length on keypress instead of waiting for them to tab or click out?

Update:

If I move

```
<md-error *ngIf="shortForm.get('fName').hasError('maxlength')">
 Maximum of 50 characters
</md-error>
```

to the outside of md-input-container, the error message displayed in keypress. Is this possibly a bug within angular material?

Update #2:
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4027

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the input gets marked as `touched` once it is blurred. As a default, `md-error` is shown when the invalid control is touched. You can change it to show when dirty using a custom `errorStateMatcher`.

See the [input docs](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview).

*app.component.html*

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput type="text" formControlName="fName" placeholder="First Name" [errorStateMatcher]="dirtyMatcher">
  <md-error *ngIf="fNameControl.hasError('maxlength')">
    Maximum of 50 characters
   </md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
/** Whether the invalid control is dirty or submitted */
dirtyMatcher(control: FormControl, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm): boolean {
  const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
  return !!(control.invalid && (control.dirty || isSubmitted)));
}
```

Also checkout this [plunker showing an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tjhIXpdhF66Zt6IfjBEZ?p=preview).

---

EDIT: There is also a global option to always show errors on dirty for all inputs (see the input docs). Also, you can make the errorStateMatcher as complicated as you need (you will need to `.bind(this)` in the template if you wish to use instance properties in your error state calculation).

Comment: How come I get ```ERROR form.component.ts (86,82): ';' expected.``` on the semi colon at end of the return?

Comment: Probably missing a closing parentheses in your method or elsewhere in your class, but there's no way for me to know without your code. You can see that it works fine in the plunker I linked

Comment: Its only when I add the chunk of code. Otherwise, everything else is valid. Could this be typescript related?

Answer (score 0):

The default Angular validation validates every time the value changes (so basically on keypress). You are however checking `touched`. That is what is making it wait for the user to tab or leave the field.

Just remove the `.touched` expression and it should work as you require.

Comment: Tried that but it still does not display <md-error>.  However, I know the validator is working on keypress because my error object output:  First name rules: {{ shortForm.get('fName').errors | json }}  updates on keypress.